Dynamic Token In A Module | Aptos MOVE
I'm new to Aptos Move,
I'm writing a module to allow dynamic token as Solidity. In Solidity, we can pass the ERC20 address into the constructor, the smart contract will parse this address to an ERC20 smart contract and call transferFrom function to transfer an amount of token from sender to this smart contract.
With a different architecture, according to my current knowledge, when constructing a module in Aptos Move, the owner still has to declare the type of token by function_name<address:token's module>(parameters). But the users calling functions related to the token have to include this function_name<address:token's module>(parameters) too.
Summary: I'm wondering that in Solidity, users don't have to care too much about the blockchain, such as the address of the token, I just know that they have an amount of this token, so they can call some functions. However, in Aptos, users have to clearly declare what token they want to use.
Is the way I mention in Aptos Move when transferring tokens a standard and common way? Or did I misunderstand any part?
Thanks in advance for your guidance!
